# Fourier transform of specific function

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

Let $$f(t) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-t}, & \text{if } t>0 \\
-e^t, & \text{if } t<0
\end{cases}$$ then compute Fourier transform of $f(t)$.

By definition we know that $$\hat{f}(\xi)=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-2\pi i t \xi}dt=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{0}f(t)e^{-2\pi i t \xi}dt+\int \limits_{0}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-2\pi i t \xi}dt=J+I$$
Then $$I=\int \limits_{0}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-2\pi i t \xi}dt=\int \limits_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-t-2\pi i t \xi}dt=\int \limits_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-t(1+2\pi i  \xi)}dt=\dfrac{1}{1+2\pi i  \xi}$$
and $$J=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{0}f(t)e^{-2\pi i t \xi}dt=-\int \limits_{-\infty}^{0}e^{t(1-2\pi i  \xi)}dt=-\dfrac{1}{1-2\pi i  \xi}$$

Hence $\hat{f}(\xi)=\dfrac{4\pi i\xi}{4\pi^2   \xi^2-1}$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: I think that you made a sign error when you added $I$ and $J$. I get another result, both when I do the addition and when I solve the problem in another way.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using distributions**

The function satisfies the distributional differential equation $f'' - f = 2\delta'.$

Taking the Fourier transform of both sides gives
$$(2\pi i\xi)^2 \hat{f} - \hat{f} = 2(2\pi i\xi),$$
i.e.
$$\hat{f} = \frac{4\pi i\xi}{(2\pi i\xi)^2-1} = -\frac{4\pi i\xi}{4\pi^2\xi^2+1}.$$